# How to write Springboot application logs to a postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

How you can implement transactions in the database, like logging? For example, the user is logged in and this is immediately written to the table.

Comment: Where user is logged in? To java application? To spring application? Or to postgres?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add. Yes. the application is on spring-boot and hibernate, I want to make logs in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My plan of implementing your example.

1. Create login page (login, password) with url mapping `/login`. When user writes his credentials, a controller redirects him from `/login` to `/success-login` page.
2. Create controller with get mapping `/success-login`. When user gets to this page, it means that he is logged in. So here you can write an sql query to postgres table, something like `id="1", user="user1", event="log in"`

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Log {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    String user;
    String event;

// getters, setters, equals, hashcode ...
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface LogRepository extends CrudRepository<Log, Long> {
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    LogRepository logRepository;

    @GetMapping("/login-success")
    public String loginSuccess() {
        Log log = new Log();
        log.setUser("user1");
        log.setEvent("log in");
        logRepository.save(log);
        return "login-success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's all ready, I have a full-fledged code) can you show how it will look exactly using SQL queries?) this is exactly what I need, because I already have a full-fledged project :)

Comment: I've added code example. There is no SQL querries, because spring boot will do all job for you :) just create new Log object and save it to repository